# Flexbox align-center makes parent container misaligned

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to vertically align the images in image containers that are laid out side by side.

However, when I applied the `align-self: center` to the children, the second-to-last parent becomes a little misaligned.

I've been trying different ways to correct this, but unless I stop using `display: flex` on the child image the issue will reappear.

The issue seems to be the car images are originally 37.5px height and 50px width, but the view more has 50px height and width. However, I think that difference should be taken care of in the parent's code where height and width are both set to 50px. But in the page inspect element tells me the car image parent height is 3px less than the following container.

```css
.imageContainer {
  height: $thumbnail_image_side_length;
  width: $thumbnail_image_side_length;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<button onClick={method here}>
    <div className="imageContainer">
        <img src={} alt='thumbnail' />
    </div>
    <p>{text here}</p>
</button>
```

This is what it looks like in the page:

[image]

Comment: share full code

Comment: @TemaniAfif Added html markup as well

Comment: Please put up a simplified working example to demonstrate the issue

Comment: Also you should remove `display: flex;` from the image tag, it cannot contain other tags

Comment: @Huangism I'm working on a fiddle, will update soon

Comment: Problem is solved with Niche's answer. I did not give the button's parent a flex display, after adding `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` to button's parent the buttons are now aligned correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're applying the flex property too far nested into the html. If you're wrapping your buttons in a container (which I guess has buttons set as `display: inline-block`), you should remove the display property from your buttons and set `display: inline-flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap` on the button container.

Check out this quick snippet I made to solve your problem.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container button {
  width: 50%;
}

.imageContainer {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button onClick={method here}>
      <div className="imageContainer">
          <img src="" alt='thumbnail' />
      </div>
      <p>{text here}</p>
  </button>
  <button onClick={method here}>
      <div className="imageContainer">
          <img src="" alt='thumbnail' />
      </div>
      <p>{text here}</p>
  </button>
  <button onClick={method here}>
      <div className="imageContainer">
          <img src="" alt='thumbnail' />
      </div>
      <p>{text here}</p>
  </button>
  <button onClick={method here}>
      <div className="imageContainer">
          <img src="" alt='thumbnail' />
      </div>
      <p>{text here}</p>
  </button>
</div>
```